# git clone : recover contained a folder in a repository

Tags: git, github, repository, clone

how to recover the contained a record of a deposit without having to recover the entire deposit?

For example, I do not want to recover it contained: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v2.0.0/less

Comment: This question is very unclear. Are you trying to checkout just a single folder from your repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve only the last commit without cloning the whole repo, you can do

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git
```

If you don't want the last commit on the main branch, but rather a single given commit, then it's impossible in general.